# Why can't I type to certain input fields on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a weird phenomenon on a Windows 10 laptop recently. When I try to login with MS account I cannot type the email and password, but when I cancel and login without password the keyboard works. I can use word, notepad, etc.

First I thought that the keyboard driver is not loaded at startup or it is a driver issue, but when I click on "this computer" and try to search a file the same happens. I can select the input with the cursor, the focus is on it, but when I type nothing shows up in it. I am not sure what is causing this, I never encountered this kind of OS problem in the past 25 years. Any idea, explanation?

Comment: note: Maybe this is related: https://www.wintips.org/fix-cannot-type-in-windows-10-search-bar/ I'll check later. I guess this is some sort of DE issue (with Linux terms) and maybe updates can solve it.

Comment: Failing that, when you get logged in, make a new, test Windows User. Make this user a Member of Administrators. Restart and log in as the new user. Does this work?

Comment: @John I don't have access to this laptop atm. I can try it out in a few days. Normally I would not care, because it is not mine, but I find this problem very interesting.